# KMO analysis returning 0.5 MSA for every variable

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I'm running a KMO analysis in R to determine factorability of data using KMO(data_matrix) function. I read that this is a recommended step as part of structural equation modeling, to determine whether the data is suitable for factorising (part of EFA). The output is an overall "MSA" value for the data set as well as individual ones for each attribute. Generally, if MSA above 0.7 it is considered that factorising is a suitable step for the data. I expected to get a range of values for different attributes, but I have gotten 0.5 for every one. This leads me to thing that either my data set is not suitable for the KMO test or large data sets in general are not suitable for factorizing.

I have quite a large data set, of about 50K rows and 25 attributes.

Any insight on why it would return this value for every attribute? Could this be a legitimate result? How important is KMO test, and does anyone have advise for where to go from here if wanting to do SEM? Is it simply not a good option?

Comment: Have you read any questions about "KMO factor analysis" on this site yet?

Comment: Yes, nothing similar to my question from what I could see. Why?

Comment: KMO 0.5 for many variables is not good, too low for FA. Your variables look like correlating mostly in pairs. Do your KMO values still vary?

Comment: Try also to cross check the computation of KMO against another package or program.